# Cómo mapear la respuesta del getAll Spring boot

Tags: api, spring, spring-boot, rest, response

Tengo una duda respecto a como se muestran los datos en un getAll. Digamos cuando devuelve un listado de objetos yo quisiera poder devolver algo más a parte del listado.

Por ejemplo supongamos que la url: "/api/clientes" devuelve:

```
[ {"id": "1", "nombre": "Salvador"}, {"id": "2", "nombre": "Alfredo"}]
```

Ahora yo quiero que esa url me devuelva algo como:

```
[ "count": 2, "rows":  {"id": "1", "nombre": "Salvador"}, {"id": "2", "nombre": "Alfredo"} ]
```

He visto algunas apis que devuelven de esa forma pero no sé si en este caso me funcione con ResponseEntity o se usan otras cosas. No tengo conocimientos en Spring.

Si alguien pudiera decirme qué debo investigar para tratar de implementarlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUCIÓN** Encontrada hasta el momento:

El tipo de respuesta lo declaro de tipo `ResponseEntity` luego creo un objeto de tipo `Map` y a ese objeto le voy metiendo la respuesta que deseo con `response.put`

```
 public ResponseEntity<?> index() {
    List<Producto> objNew = null;
    Map<String, Object> response = new HashMap<>();
    try {
        objNew = objService.getAll();
    } catch (DataAccessException ex) {
        response.put("mensaje", "Error al obtener de la base de datos");
        response.put("error", ex.getMessage().concat(": ").concat(ex.getMostSpecificCause().getMessage()));
        return new ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>>(response, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }

    response.put("size", objNew.size());
    response.put("rows", objNew);

    return new ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>>(response, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

Y ahora mi respuesta es así (Justo como la quiero):

```
{
"size": 2,
"rows": [
    {
        "createdAt": "2020-02-15T23:07:52.000+0000",
        "updatedAt": "2020-02-15T23:07:52.000+0000",
        "id": 1,
        "nombre": "Prueba insert",
        "descripcion": "Prueba",
        "precio": 15.0,
        "tipo": "Bebida"
    },
    {
        "createdAt": "2020-02-15T23:16:02.000+0000",
        "updatedAt": "2020-02-15T23:16:02.000+0000",
        "id": 2,
        "nombre": "Prueba inserddddt",
        "descripcion": "Pruddddeba",
        "precio": 154.0,
        "tipo": "Bebida"
    }
]
```

}